# How does the Dash package work in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, plotly-dash

I'm learning the package [Dash](https://github.com/plotly/dash) which is the most popular package about making a webpage for a dashboard. The following is the sample code:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback

import plotly.express as px
import json

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
fig = px.scatter(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[1, 2, 3])
fig.update_layout(clickmode='event+select')

fig.update_traces(marker_size=20)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='basic-interactions',
        figure=fig
    ),
    html.Div(id="hover-data"),
    html.Div(id="click-data"),
])


@callback(
    Output('hover-data', 'children'),
    Input('basic-interactions', 'hoverData'))
def display_hover_data(hoverData):
    return str(hoverData)

@callback(
    Output('click-data', 'children'),
    Input('basic-interactions', 'clickData'))
def display_click_data(clickData):
    return json.dumps(clickData, indent=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port="8081")
```

I'm trying to understand where the function `display_hover_data`'s argument `hoverData` comes from?

Is it from the post `response` on url `_dash-update-component`?

```
    def _setup_routes(self):
        self._add_url(
            "_dash-component-suites/<string:package_name>/<path:fingerprinted_path>",
            self.serve_component_suites,
        )
        self._add_url("_dash-layout", self.serve_layout)
        self._add_url("_dash-dependencies", self.dependencies)
        self._add_url("_dash-update-component", self.dispatch, ["POST"])
        self._add_url("_reload-hash", self.serve_reload_hash)
        self._add_url("_favicon.ico", self._serve_default_favicon)
        self._add_url("", self.index)

        if jupyter_dash.active:
            self._add_url(
                "_alive_" + jupyter_dash.alive_token, jupyter_dash.serve_alive
            )

        # catch-all for front-end routes, used by dcc.Location
        self._add_url("<path:path>", self.index)
```

Comment: so what does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: `hoverData` is just the param of the function. You can call it anything you want. But that data for that param comes from the input - `Input('basic-interactions', 'hoverData')` So you are getting the hover data from the graph with the following ID `basic-interactions`

Comment: @Pointy, this package is based on JavaScript, so I guess the one which has knowlege of javascript can help me.

Comment: @It_is_Chris, yes I know. But how it constructs the object `hoverData`? What information is needed to contruct the object? Does the formation come from the post on url "/_dash-update-component"?

Comment: Yes, from the post requests to `_dash-update-component` Here is the payload `{"output":"hover-data.children","outputs":{"id":"hover-data","property":"children"},"inputs":[{"id":"basic-interactions","property":"hoverData","value":{"points":[{"curveNumber":0,"pointNumber":0,"pointIndex":0,"x":"a","y":1,"bbox":{"x0":153.7,"x1":173.7,"y0":340,"y1":360}}]}}],"changedPropIds":["basic-interactions.hoverData"]}`

Comment: @It_is_Chris May I ask you a noob question: how did you get the payload information above? It took me 2 days to guess that the post response information would be look like that you mentioned, I just can't get it out.

Comment: I will post an answer that way I can include screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On callbacks it looks like there is a post request to `_dash-update-component`. For the `hover` event, the payload for that requests is

```
{"output":"hover-data.children","outputs":{"id":"hover-data","property":"children"},"inputs":[{"id":"basic-interactions","property":"hoverData","value":{"points":[{"curveNumber":0,"pointNumber":0,"pointIndex":0,"x":"a","y":1,"bbox":{"x0":153.7,"x1":173.7,"y0":340,"y1":360}}]}}],"changedPropIds":["basic-interactions.hoverData"]}
```

You can get this information from your browser by inspecting the source code, navigating to the network tab, and selecting `Fetch/XHR`. You can then cause an event to happen by hovering over a point and selecting it from the list on the left.

[image]

You can see the response by select response instead of payload. All browsers have similar tools but I am using Chrome.

A click without a callback uses a javascript function found in `plotly.min.js` (I believe `function _(a)`) If you remove the `mousedown` from the event listener nothing will happen when you click on the graph.

[image]

Comment: One more asking:
When I have the above two callback functions `display_hover_data` and `display_click_data`, then there is two kinds of `POST` in the web. When I have only one callback function `display_hover_data`, then when I click the data, there is no `POST`(as expected). But how it happened, is it because that clicking data does't make a `request` on the `POST` url? What is it behind the web that make it choose not to make the `request`?

Comment: How does the package make the request on url `/_dash-update-component`? If the request is always made whenever hovering or clicking a data, why when I have only one callback function `display_hove_data`, clicking data doesn't make a request?

Comment: As for "why when I have only one callback function display_hove_data, clicking data doesn't make a request?" that is because I believe the post requests for the event only happens when there is a callabck. So clicking on a point without an input with `clickData` wont post any data. If you want the click data you will need to add that input to the `display_hove_data` callback or have a different callback function like you currently have `display_click_data`